# liftweb menu with submenus

Tags: scala, lift

I create menu in liftweb here is my code

```
 def sitemap() = SiteMap(
  Menu("Menu1") / "menu1" submenus(
          Menu("Submenu1") / "submenu1" ,
          Menu("Submenu2") / "submenu2",
          Menu("Submenu3") / "submenu3"),
  Menu("Menu2") / "menu2"
)
```

It works but when I select Menu1 it display menu1.html page, but I want submenu1 page been displayed by default

I realize that it should be very simple but I'm very beginner in lift and can't figure out how to do it

Comment: See Question "How should I create customized menu with Lift framework?"

Comment: My answer would be `Menu("Menu1") / "submenu1"`. Correct me if I am wrong, otherwise I will post this answer in order to close this question

Comment: @ChrisJamesC it wouldn't work. The only solution I have found was to redirect response from Menu1 to Submenu1.

Comment: @AlexanderZhugastrov i'm sorry but i don't know the answer if this attempt was wrong

Answer (score 0):

LiftRules.dispatch seems good,look like that:

```
 LiftRules.dispatch.prepend {
    case Req("menu1" :: Nil, _, _) => () =>{
        Full(RedirectResponse("/submenu1"))
    }           
 }
```

http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-3.html#toc-Section-3.8